# Ajax - Replace content

Tags: ajax

here my code.

```
<a href="#" id="bar_save" class="bar_save"> Save</a> |
<a href="#" id="bar_unsave" class="bar_unsave"> Unsave</a> |
```

In my Ajax code, when user clicks on Save, it saves one information into my mysql table. Then, when he clicks on unsave, it deletes it.

What i want to do:
When user clicks on save, it displays `<a href="#" id="bar_unsave" class="bar_unsave"> Unsave</a>`  instead `<a href="#" id="bar_save" class="bar_save"> save</a>.`

I've tried with
`$('#bar_save').text('<a href="#" id="bar_unsave" class="bar_unsave"> Unsave</a>');` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set bar_unsave to be hidden by default. Show bar_unsave on user 'save' action and hide bar_save.

```
$('#bar_save').addClass("hidden");
$('#bar_unsave').removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer.Yeah, i know how to add text into a tag. But i wanna add html code too. Look at my example.

Comment: If you hide bar_save and show bar_unsave, will it work for you?

Comment: Hi, i've tried with $('#bar_save_span').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="save" class="bar_unsave"> No follow</a>');  it works, i've the html code but my ajax doesnt work after that. User can't unsave. I will try ur method

Answer (score 0):

I can't use your methode hidden because i do mysql query.

Here my whole code.

```
 <?php
    if($fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
<?php
    $req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM membres_save WHERE id=\'' . $_GET['id'] . '\'');
    if ($req->rowCount() == 0) {
      ?>
      <span id ="bar_save_span"><a href="#" id="bar_save" class="bar_save"> Save</a></span> |
    <?php }
    else { 
    ?>
      <span id ="bar_unsave_span"><a href="#" id="unsave" class="bar_unsave"> Unsave </a></span> |
    <?php    }  } ?>
```

I've tried with

```
$('#dbar_save_span').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="unsave" class="bar_unsave"> Unsave </a>');
```

When user clicks on save, it display this html code but when user clicks on unsave, my ajax function doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, with this code (above), it displays the right code but when i click on Unsave, my ajax function doesn't work. If i refresh the page, it works. I would like to do it without refresh the whole page. Is it possible ?